# How can I use VBA in Excel to send out meeting requests on behalf of another calendar?

Tags: excel, calendar, outlook, vba

I am posting this request a second time , since although I have had a reply from JimmyPena, the solution didn't work and I do not seem to be able to add my comments as to what happened. The VBA code is in the Excel spreadsheet not Outlook.

I am trying to write some VB code within Excel 2007 that will automatically send out meeting invites from the Outlook 2007 Calendar, to a list of addressees listed in the excel spreadsheet, on the dates specified within the spreadsheet. This is useful because I can send out hundreds of meeting requests to different people on different dates with one click of a button. I can do this fine when sending from my own user account with the following code:

```
' Create the Outlook session 
Set myoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
' Create the AppointmentItem 
Set myapt = myoutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)     ' Set the appointment properties 
With myapt 
    .Subject = " Assessment Centre " 
    .Location = "conference room A" 
    .Start = Cells(5, 24 + j) & " 17:00:00 PM" 
    .Duration = 120 
    .Recipients.Add Cells(i, 1).Value 
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
    ' not necessary if recipients are email addresses 
    'myapt.Recipients.ResolveAll 
    .AllDayEvent = "False" 
    .BusyStatus = "2" 
    .ReminderSet = False 
    .Body = L1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & L2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & L3 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & L4 
        .Save 
    .send 
End With
```

But now I want to send the meeting request from a dummy user account for which I am a delegate using something like ’sendonbehalfof’ so that the dummy calendar stores all the meeting invites, and other delegates can operate the system as well using the same dummy user account. This works fine when sending an email with the following code:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0) 

With oMail 
    .To = " John.Smith@John_Smith.com " 
    .Subject = "Subject" 
    .Body = "Body" 
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Fred.bloggs@fred_blogs.com" 
    .send 
End With
```

The email will say from ’me on behalf of Fred Bloggs’

But I can’t get it to work with Calendar appointments.

I’ve searched high and low with words like ‘appointment’, ‘meeting request’, sendonbehalfof’ etc, and it seems you should be able to do this for appointments with ’sendusingaccount’ but this doesn’t seem to work (it doesn’t fail, just ignores the instruction and sends from my own user account as before).
Can anyone tell me how to do this? 
. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered generating an Internet Calendar Appointment (ICA) request and emailing it? I believe that format contains delegate information that you can use.

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb655909%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to some Microsoft documentation on how to add this (in ASP.Net, but that shouldn't matter) and [here is a link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) to the IETF RFC that defines the format.

Comment: Competent-tech  Thanks very much for the reply. Unfortunately, I am such a novice, I don't understand what to do here. The meeting request only has to go out on my internal Company e-mail sytem using Outlook. Is there any fundamental reason why there can't be  a function for appointments like 'sentonbehalfofname' in the e-mail example above?